# How do I get a refund on an iOS app I just bought?

Tags: itunes, applications, ios-appstore

I just bought an iPhone app knowing that it may or may not provide the feature which was the entire reason for me buying it.  I figured I could always get a refund if it doesn't do what I want.  It doesn't.  But now I've realized I don't know how to get a refund.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not had success with "Reporting a problem," because my requests have been ignored in three different cases now.

Here's my workflow that has worked for me each time:

- Purchase App
- Find something wrong with App
- Report a problem (it will be ignored, but do this just to say you did)
- Contact credit card provider and dispute the charge with your reasons (mine are usually "software did not work at all" or "as promised")
- Wait 3-5 business days
- Credit card provider resolves dispute, issues refund
- Apple disables AppleID due to "security risk" of account access
- Contact apple support by emailing or asking for a phone call
- Wait 1-2 business days for response
- Kindly explain what happened, they respond by following a walkthrough of re-enabling your account after verifying security questions

Answer (score 7):

In iTunes, go to *Store* ->*View My Account* ->*Purchase History*. Select *Report a Problem*. Fill out the form explaining what happened, and Apple will get back to you with information about whether your refund has been approved or denied.

Comment: I did this, but after selecting "Application does not work as expected" and typing in my explanation, including request for refund, I got a message that I need to ask the developer for support and the developer's web page opened in Safari.  I guess I won't be getting a refund.

Comment: @Daryl Unless the developer deliberately mislead you, it's highly unlikely that you'll get a refund from Apple. Sorry.

Comment: Apple never responds to these